# .net Menu control SelectedItem always null on homepage

Tags: asp.net, .net, menu, webforms

I am using a .net webforms Menu control generated from the following sitemap:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="" title="NavigationWrapper"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="/" title="Home"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="/search" title="Search"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="/contact" title="Contact"  description="" />     
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

When I click the home link, the SelectedItem property of the menu control is always null, but it works fine when clicking the other two links. I can't seem to work out why!

The only way I can seem to get around this is to create a www.abc.com/home link for my homepage, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Any help much appreciated!

Edit:

Route Collection is as follows:

```
        routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "", "~/Default.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("Search", "search", "~/SearchByMap.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("contact", "contact", "~/Contact.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="/search" title="Search"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="/contact" title="Contact"  description="" />     
</siteMapNode>
```

Add this to your route collection:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Home", "", "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: That would work, but then I have to have www.abc.com/home as my homepage, which I don't really want to do.

Comment: What happens if you do: `url="~"` or even `url="~/"` ?

Comment: No change with either of those.  If I set it to url="Default.aspx", it then works, but the link then goes directly to www.domain.com/Default.aspx, rather than www.domain.com

Comment: Just seen your edit, leaving the route string empty in MapPageRoutes stops the link from working (it tries to go to www.domain.com/ then a GUID?!).  I also tried setting it to "/", but that gives an error.

Comment: Did you change the sitemapNode url accordingly? `<siteMapNode url="" title="Home"  description="">` If it still does not work... please, post your route config in your question.

Comment: Try this now: `<siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">`

Comment: Yes I did, it actually appears to be that which causes the weird behaviour with the GUID in the url.  Changing the route string to "" actually seems to have no effect.  If I change it to go to a different aspx page, it still just goes to the homepage.  Added my RouteCollection above.

Comment: Changing it the url to Default.aspx works, and worked all along, it's just that then the link it going to www.domain.com/Default.aspx, when I'd prefer it to be www.domain.com